# Smooth scrolling to anchor links and lazyloaded images

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, smooth-scrolling

I have a page with a number of lazy loaded images and I'm trying to scroll to anchors on the same page but problem is the images are responsive and the height can vary so scroll takes me to the wrong place in the place in this page. My best guess it's because when the scrolling is executed the images are not yet rendered and so the scroll function does not know the height of the images.

Is there some workaround?

Comment: You could have a base64 placeholder

Comment: even if I don't know the size of the images?

Comment: If you use a base64 placeholder the size will be already set

Comment: I tried setting this `url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mNkYAAAAAYAAjCB0C8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);`as background-image on my img tags but that didn't help me.